# Create Hyperlinks from controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller, which creates breadcrumbs as follows:

```
Software > Windows 7 > Outlook 2007
```

The code to create this is:

```
ViewBag.breadcrumbs = string.Join(" > ", cbh.Select(i => i.Title));
```

Is there a straightforward way of making the breadcrumbs hyperlinks, which would point to (i.ParentID) ie:

```
Software -> forum/index/12
Windows 7 -> forum/index/19
Outlook 2007 -> forum/index/23
```

Or should I just loop through **cbh** and manually build **<a href=...>** strings, and pass those to the view?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to put the required items into the model then loop through them.

Try something like this:

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public struct BreadCrumb
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Url;
    }

    public List<BreadCrumb> Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@{ int index = 0; }
@foreach(var crumb in this.Model.Breadcrumbs)
{
    <a href="@(crumb.Url)" title="@(crumb.Title)">@(crumb.Title)</a>

    if(index < this.Model.Breadcrumbs.Count - 1)
    {
        <span>&gt;</span>
    }

    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should build your breadcrumb links in the view. If it helps, you can create a `BreadCrumbModel` class (if you don't already have one).

```
ViewBag.breadcrumbs = cbh.Select(i => new BreadCrumbModel() 
                                      {
                                          Id = i.Id, 
                                          Title = i.Title 
                                      });

@{ 
    var printSeparator = false;
}
@foreach(BreadCrumbModel bc in ViewBag.breadcrumbs)
{
    @if(printSeparator)
    {
        <span class="breadcrumb-separator">&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
    }
    <span class="breadcrumb">
      @Html.ActionLink(bc.Title, "index", "forum", new { id = bc.Id });
    </span>
    @{
        printSeparator = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to have breadcrumbs between different controllers and actions (not just forum / index), then add those as properties of your `BreadCrumbModel`.